# Why do Chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe still appear in the computer's memory, despite using driver.close() and driver.quit()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

The code I've written successfully does its part in crawling through a website with the appropriate date and time formatted in the URL, grabbing the table from the underlying HTML source code, and appending the results to a cache.

This python file gets run several dozen times (there are many agent IDs whose info I need to grab); after the script runs, however, dozens of `chrome.exe` and `chromedriver.exe` instances still appear in the computer's memory (this is visible in the computer's "Resource Monitor.")

Below is my code. I've used `driver.quit()` as well as `driver.close()` and even both together (with `driver.close()` coming first).

Isn't the `driver.quit()` supposed to close the instances in the computer's system? Why are they appearing in the memory? Is there a solution to this issue?

Please let me know if I can provide any further information. Thank you in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import credentials_page

def get_updated_url(agent_id_num):
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    today = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    previous_date_string = str(yesterday)[:10]
    return 'https://examplewebsite.com/agentId/'+agent_id_num+'/orderBy/ASC/startDate/'+previous_date_string+'%204:00%20AM/endDate/'+previous_date_string+'%2010:30%20PM'

def login_entry(username, password, browser): # logs into website
    login_email = browser.find_element_by_id('UserName')
    login_email.send_keys(username)
    login_password = browser.find_element_by_id('Password')
    login_password.send_keys(password)
    submit_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Log in')]")
    submit_elem.click()

def get_element(xpath, browser): # grabs element, turns it into needed table in raw HTML format
    table_of_interest = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    # this has a type of <class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
    return str('<table>'+table_of_interest.get_attribute('innerHTML')+'</table>')

def record_source_code(destination_cache, get_element_html): # takes element HTML and writes it to cache
    code_destination = open(destination_cache, 'w')
    code_destination.write(repr(get_element_html))
    code_destination.close()

def main_function(agent_id):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    # figure out strings for start_date, end_date
    url = get_updated_url(agent_id)
    driver.get(url)
    #login
    login_entry(credentials_page.website_username, credentials_page.website_password, driver)
    # first test to see if "not found"
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='Not Found']"))>0:
        logoff_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Log off')]")
        logoff_elem.click()
        driver.quit()
        return False
    else:
        #grab table needed
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody')))
        table_html = get_element('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody', driver)
        driver.quit()
        record_source_code('results_cache.html', table_html)
        return True
```

Comment: Not sure why quit() does not close the instance, but you can possibly try a workaround by using os.system() to kill the chromedriver process

Comment: @SmartDumb Thanks- I'll give that a try momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

I think the root cause is your code doesn't handle an exception. So when an exception occurs, it won't quit. Try/catch should help.

```
def main_function(agent_id):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    # figure out strings for start_date, end_date
    url = get_updated_url(agent_id)
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        #login
        login_entry(credentials_page.website_username, credentials_page.website_password, driver)
        # first test to see if "not found"
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='Not Found']"))>0:
            logoff_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Log off')]")
            logoff_elem.click()
            driver.quit()
            return False
        else:
            #grab table needed
            WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody')))
            table_html = get_element('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody', driver)
            driver.quit()
            record_source_code('results_cache.html', table_html)
            return True
    except:
        drier.quit() #<-- Try/catch and close it
```